# Customize the FF DOM Inspector

Tags: firefox, dom-inspector

How can I customize the Firefox DOM Inspector? The white color and the font size makes it difficult to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. I used Stylish addon 
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/

```
@namespace url(http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml);

@-moz-document url("chrome://browser/content/devtools/markup-view.xhtml") {

body { background: white !important }

}
```

The above is a sample for the background only. Another css example is one below.

```
/* This Source Code Form is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public
 * License, v. 2.0. If a copy of the MPL was not distributed with this
 * file, You can obtain one at http://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/. */

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  color: hsl(0,0%,50%);
  background: black !important;
}

.text {
  color: white !important;
}

.newattr {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.selected {
  background-color: hsl(0,0%,90%);
}

/* Give some padding to focusable elements to match the editor input
 * that will replace them. */
span[tabindex] {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1px 0;
}

li.container {
  position: relative;
  padding: 2px 0 0 2px;
}

.codebox {
  padding-left: 14px;
}

.expander {
  position: absolute;
  -moz-appearance: treetwisty;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
}

.expander[expanded] {
  -moz-appearance: treetwistyopen;
}

.more-nodes {
  padding-left: 16px;
}

.styleinspector-propertyeditor {
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
}


}
```

[Source](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/943857)

Comment: can you help me with similar url for webconsole, i want to change the font-size but could not get the target url

Comment: Can you elaborate please? I 'm an intermediate user so while I cannot assure you that I'll be able to solve your needs, I ll give it a try.

Comment: oh well its done. I was trying to style websole, but could not get the target url, but found it.